# Numbers between 1 and 2014 are divisible by 2 but are not divisible by 5 and 7?

Tags: number-theory

I could help with the following exercise please.

How many numbers between 1 and 2014 are divisible by 2 but are not divisible by 5 and 7?

Comment: What have you tried?  What numbers are divisible by 5 and 7?  If you don't know where to start, get a spreadsheet to check the first hundred or so and look for a pattern.  You could even get it to check all the numbers from 1 to 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. of numbers divisible by n between 1 and 2014 = 2014/n.
(Note: we have to do only integer division)

(Below the number K represent set of numbers divisible by K between 1 and 2014.)

Essentially what you need is the following set:
[image]
$$|2 \cap (5 \cup 7)'|$$
$$ = |2| - |2 \cap 5| - |2 \cap 7| + |2 \cap 5 \cap 7|$$
$$ = |2| - |10| - |14| + |70|$$
$$ = 1007 - 201 - 143 + 28$$
$$ = 691$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Numbers divisible by 2 are even numbers. How many numbers are even between 1 and 2014?

Numbers divisible by 5 *and* 7 are divisible by the least common multiple $lcm(5,7) = 35$. How many of the even numbers are also divisible by 35 (i.e. how many multiples of 35 are even)? Subtracting that number from the total number of even numbers gives you the result.

Comment: This will oversubtract those numbers which are divisible by 35 from even numbers.

Comment: @swapniel99 Note that I wrote about even multiples of 35, not just multiples of 35.